# Undefined variable problema con $_POST

Tags: php

Tengo un problema con **$_POST[]** . Mira tengo un formulario al que le estoy agregando un **input type hidden** para enviar por "Ahí" una variable, esa variable se llama **$valorID** y la muestro en este código:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE user='$userD' and tokenUser='$tokenD'";
$resultado2 =mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
$datoID=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado2);

$valorID =$datoID['id'];
```

?>

```
<p class="">Por favor escribe una <strong>nueva contraseña</strong> para acceder a tu cuenta
<p>
<form method="post" action="pagina_iniciar_sesion.php">


    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="etiquetas_crear_cuenta  col-5 float-left"><strong>Nueva Contraseña:</strong><small id='' class='<?= $pass ?> form-text text-muted'>8 caracteres minimo</small></label>
        <input type="text" name="newpass1" class="form-control col-7 d-inline-block" id="">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="etiquetas_crear_cuenta  col-5 float-left"><strong>Repetir Contraseña:</strong><small id='' class='<?= $pass ?> form-text text-muted'>Repite contraseña</small></label>
        <input type="text" name="newpass2" class="form-control col-7 d-inline-block" id="">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden"  value="<?php $valorID ?>" >
   

    <button type="submit" value="" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

La variable lleva el numero **1**  (Todo bien) pero cuando envió el formulario del otro lado recibo el siguiente error:

**Warning: Undefined variable $valorID in D:\xampp\htdocs\area_login\archivos\formulario_iniciar_sesion.php on line 8**

El código donde necesito recibir esa variable **$valorID** empieza algo así y rapidamente hago un **echo** para comprobar si **$_POST[$valorID]** "VIENE desde el formulario anterior y pues no... me salta el error anterior (El código es este):

```
 <?php if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
    echo "<div class='bg-warning mb-2 col border rounded'><p class=' text-dark h-25'> <strong>* Los datos son incorrectos</strong></p></div>";
} else {
    "";
}
echo $_POST[$valorID];
```

Mi pregunta es:

¿Estoy enviando de manera correcta la variable  **$valorID** por el campo value del input hidden? Ya que necesito esa variable **$valorID** para poder actualizar las contraseñas del usuario y las envió por "POST" para que sea de forma segura.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Te falta el atributo name en el input hidden

Comment: @Yussef ya se lo había puesto y no funciono (Se supone que en el value="" es por donde envió la variable **$valorID** ¿No?

Comment: @FranciscoJavier Ya le hice un "echo" y en efecto va un string con un valor de =1 así que el error no va ahí

Comment: @FranciscoJavier mmm no estoy seguro si fuera o no el error... Lo que pasa es que el formulario_iniciar_sesion.php es un archivo .php que **PERTENECE** por medio de un include a  pagina_iniciar_sesion.php ... 

En teoría debería funcionar ¿No?

Comment: cuando haces un post el atributo name de los inputs NO es opcional. El name debe ser el mismo que ocupas en el PHP cuando lo recibes. name="unnombre"  --> $_POST['unnombre'];. Por otro lado el value es el valor que tiene almacenada la variable

Comment: @Ok ¿Entonces en código como quedaría? **$_POST [y el nombre del "name"]** y por ahí saco el **$valorID** que va por **value="$valorID"** ??

Comment: Exacto y ojo que aca type="hidden"  value="<?php $valorID ?>" también te falta un echo antes de $valorID

Comment: Pues no... No se envia nada, lo puse así:

**<input type="hidden" name="valorID" value="<?php $valorID ?>" >** y nada... 

Es como si llegara el name="valorID" pero el value es como si no enviara la variable...

Osea me verifica que si llego el name pero el value no llega

Comment: Te falta el echo fíjate bien como es: <input type="hidden" name="valorID" value="<?php echo $valorID ?>" >   y el post te queda así $_POST['ValorID']

Comment: @Yussef me parece que esta funcionando (Eso creo) porque **OJO** añadi el echo como tu lo dijiste... 

Lo que no entiendo es porque si pones o no el **echo** en el value="" funciona (Es decir **NO TIENE SENTIDO... ¿NO?** (Estoy revisando si el echo hizo la diferencia...)

Comment: Tienes que pensar en PHP como un lenguaje que imprime HTML (como hay otros lenguajes que imprimen en la consola) (Antes del "echo" se ocupaba el print()) Si no imprimes algo, no será mostrado.  Incluso tu podrías poner el echo donde te plazca, podrías generar javascript, svg o lo que sea texto plano. Entonces si no colocas <?php echo $valorID ?> nunca imprimirá la variable en el documento

Comment: @Yussef Pues yo pense que la variable **$valorID** ya iba "Imprimida" (Pero ahora que lo pienso como que medio tiene sentido lo que dices) Lo pregunto solamente por el tema de la **SEGURIDAD** ya que al tratar de enviar YO un **input hidden** que lleva un valor que supuestamente no quiero que vean porque es para actualizar una contraseña por eso me resulto raro que dijeras que tenia que poner un **echo** ya que estoy evitando que alguien pueda ver el valor de esa variable... Y pense que por ser **input hidden** había que poner echo... Pensare en lo que me compartes (Gracias)

Comment: Cuando haces un post de un form lo que se envía son los inputs y select, hay varios tipos de inputs. El hidden solo hace que no se muestre en pantalla, pero está en el HTML (esta invisible). No ofrece ningún tipo seguridad, cualquiera que vea el código fuente lo va a poder ver junto con su valor y para el ver código fuente no se necesita ser un hacker ruso basta con precionar ctrl+u